# Share plugin linkedin

Tags: javascript, mobile, linkedin-api

I am using `https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=` to share content to linkedin, while this methode works fine in desktop browsers, when you click the button in mobile browsers it opens the linkedin application without the share interface.

what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing.

It just isn't compatible with the mobile app.

Comment: so what can i do ?

Comment: Complain to LinkedIn about app missing that feature.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that LinkedIn have more that one link to share content and, for some reason, the link that i used (`https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=`) didn't work on Mobile (not sure tho if it should work on Mobile or not).

So i've done some researchers and found out that there is another link that works on Mobile (i took it from nytimes's share button), this link is `https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=` and it does work.